# Variables not being used but clearly are! - Java

Tags: java, variables

So I'm getting some odd errors such as illegal start of type and variable's that are not being used when I am clearly calling them. Now I'm using the latest version of netbeans and I'm no expert at Java but I believe that my netbeans may be corrupted or something not to sure.

As far as my logic goes with these if loops everything should be ok hence the reason I'm not going to go into too much detail about what the program is being used for.

Anyway here's the code I will highlight the area's with the errors.

Thanks in Advance Regards -Skeng-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Envelope extends Parcel {

protected char[] size = {'S','M','L'};

public Envelope(){

ImageIcon imageES = new ImageIcon ("..\\Images\\envelope-small.png");
ImageIcon imageEM = new ImageIcon ("..\\Images\\envelope-medium.png");
    ImageIcon imageEL = new ImageIcon ("..\\Images\\envelope-large.png");


    double ChargeS = 4.50; 
    double ChargeM = 8.50;
    double ChargeL = 16.99;        
    double ChargeFinal = 0;   **//Variable not being used**

    if (size[0] == 'S') {
        ChargeFinal = ChargeS;
    } else if (size[1] == 'M') {
        ChargeFinal = ChargeM;
    } else if (size[2] == 'L')
        ChargeFinal = ChargeL;
    }

    int zone = 0; //Zone will equal whatever the user selects for their parcel size
    double zonecharge; //ZoneCharge will be the price depending on the zone


    if (zone == 1) {             **//Illegal Start of Type** 
        zonecharge = 0;          **//Illegal Start of Type**
     } else if (zone == 2) {     **//Illegal Start of Type**
        zonecharge = 1.5;        **//Illegal Start of Type**
     } else if (zone == 3) {     **//Illegal Start of Type**
        zonecharge = 2;          **//Illegal Start of Type**
     } 

     double EndPrice = ChargeFinal * zonecharge;  **//Cannot find Symbol "ChargeFinal"**
     System.out.println("Charge: £" + EndPrice);  **//Illegal Start of Type**


@Override
public String toString() {
return "ID: " + idNum + "Zone: " + zone + "Charge: " + charge + "Size: " + size;
}

@Override
ImageIcon getImage() {
    return image;
}
}
```

Comment: Ignoring your problem for the moment, what exactly is the point of the `if` statements after the `Charge` declarations? Only one will be executed although all three of them are trivially true.

Comment: there is a missing } before the first override

Comment: (You should also see that `zonecharge` is uninitialised. I suggest adding an `else` rather than assigning a value at declaration. The variable can be made `final`. Also, it's a good candidate for the "ternary operator" `? :`.

Comment: And inexact `double`s for money, is generally considered a bad idea.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're missing a opening bracket after the first `else if`

```
if (size[0] == 'S') {
        ChargeFinal = ChargeS;
    } else if (size[1] == 'M') {
        ChargeFinal = ChargeM;
    } else if (size[2] == 'L') { // ADD THIS BRACKET
        ChargeFinal = ChargeL;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a missing brace at the end of this line:

```
    } else if (size[2] == 'L')
```

As a result, the brace two lines later terminates the constructor, and the "Illegal start of type" warnings are coming because the next block of code is outside of any method. You can't have statements at class scope, of course!

Comment: Lol Pure DERP on my behalf. Although I my defence I was trying to program this at 5am. xD

Comment: Glad to help. A strategy for avoiding this in the future: if your compiler tells you something crazy, run the code through a formatter -- i.e., tell Eclipse to format the file, or whatever you're using. It would have pointed this problem right out.

Answer (score 1):

```
} else if (size[2] == 'L')
    ChargeFinal = ChargeL;
}  // <-- move this bracket to the end of the constructor
```

has an extra bracket, that is closing the constructor.